# C - Reuse struct as argument for multiple PThreads

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I have a while loop, and for each iteration of the loop, I am creating and populating a struct, and creating a thread while passing in that struct as an argument to the threaded function.

This is causing some issues - My while loop updates the data in the struct before my threaded function has a chance to make local copies of the struct data.

Does anyone know a good way to go about reusing a struct for multiple threads? I thought about using some kind of flag to make the main thread wait until the threaded function grabs its own copy, but this seems like it would introduce unnecessary waiting.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
struct parameters {
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int val3;
};

int main() {
    ...
    while (readLine(file)) {
        ...
        struct parameters *myParameters = malloc(sizeof(struct parameters));
        myParameters.val1 = line.val1;
        myParameters.val2 = line.val2;
        myParameters.val3 = line.val3;

        pthread_t myThread;
        pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, &print, myParameters);
        free(myParameters);
    }
}

void *print(void *param) {
    struct parameters *localParameters = param;
    int threadVal1 = localParameters->val1;
    int threadVal2 = localParameters->val2;
    int threadVal3 = localParameters->val3;
}
```

Comment: "Does anyone know a good way to go about reusing a struct for multiple threads?" Ummm... Don't. Memory is cheap, especially for that sort of use. Otherwise, you'd have to use something like a semaphore or monitor or condition variable for the child thread to signal to the parent that it's done with the info. That would be unnecessarily painful.

Comment: Unless you use some thread synchronization machanism, i don't think you can reuse the variable. But are you sure about reusing the variable in yopur code? You are declaring "myParameters" inside while loop.

Comment: @MayurK Most implementations will re-use the same stack locations for that variable even though it's technically a new one on each iteration. But that highlights an even worse problem with this code in general (although not specifically in this case) - handing a thread an address in a stack frame that may cease to exist during the lifetime of the thread is a particularly bad idea.

Comment: @twalberg Yeah. I think it is always better to malloc thread parameter and pass. There will not be any confusion.

Comment: @twalberg I changed `struct parameters myParameters` to `struct parameters *myParameters = malloc(sizeof(struct parameters));`, but It still seems as If the struct is being overwritten somehow before my thread can grab a copy. Where should I be freeing this memory?

Comment: @johnsmith101 It's probably cleanest for the thread to free the memory when it's done with it, but you could stash the pointers in an array in the main thread and free it after the threads have finished, as well. If stuff still seems to be getting overwritten, there's something else going on in the code that you aren't showing. Or maybe you're passing a pointer-to-pointer if you forgot to fix the last argument to `pthread_create()`...

Comment: @twalberg As long as I malloc the struct in the while loop, the struct will be allocated to a different chunk of memory on each iteration, correct?

Comment: @johnsmith101 Correct

Comment: @johnsmith101  I understood what you have modified. But to be sure can you update the code in your question?

Comment: @johnsmith101 You are also reusing "myThread" variable. I think that is also a problem. Can you use different variable? For testing have an array of "pthread_t" outside while() loop.

Comment: @MayurK I have updated the struct parameters to match my comment, as well as updated the pthread_create call. 

How is it a problem to reuse myThread? It's simply a thread identifier, and it changes with each iteration of the while loop. I have no need to reference the threads at a later point (such as for joining), so I don't think i need to keep track of identifiers. Also, I am creating threads as I am reading in lines from a file, so I wouldn't know how many identifiers to allocate beforehand.

Comment: @johnsmith101 Yeah understood. I assume you are doing myParameters->val1 = line.val1; Also you don't have to pass "&print" to pthread_create(). Just pass "print".